# Any advice on how to assure patients that a medical facility is well protected against identity theft?

Tags: encryption, audit, hipaa, identity-theft

My apologies if this question has been asked before.

How does a medical practice assure patients that the practice follows excellent computer security practices?

Conversely, how does a patient find this out?

Some initial questions:

1. Do any of the computers in the office run Windows XP? If so, are they air-gapped?
2. Ditto for Windows Vista.
3. Does each computer use full-disk encryption?
4. What is office policy about BYOD devices?
5. Is there a written security policy? What documents do employees sign?

These questions, and more, would be answered in a security audit. Can medical facilities provide a statement to patients about their security practices, without revealing specifically what they are?

An interesting link:

http://krebsonsecurity.com/2014/09/medical-records-for-sale-in-underground-stolen-from-texas-life-insurance-firm/

NOTE: I think that a "medical audit" does not cover security issues. A "medical audit" covers proper diagnosis and coding of medical conditions according to the ICD-10-CM (International Classification of Diseases, Tenth Revision, Clinical Modification). See http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/icd/icd10cm.htm

Answer (score 5):

As Schroeder has mentioned there are a few security standards and frameworks which can be used. One thing you absolutely are **REQUIRED to comply with by LAW**  in the U.S. (I see you live in New York) is [HIPAA](http://www.onlinetech.com/compliant-hosting/hipaa-compliant-hosting/resources/what-is-hipaa-compliance).

Aside from that the ISO 27001 can provide you with a certification that you have a controlled security organization. There are different bodies that can provide this certifications, such as EY CertifyPoint or BSI.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of regulatory bodies that provide standards and auditing procedures to provide this kind of assurance (of varying degrees and focus):

- ISO 27000
- COBIT
- NIST

As you speak of 'patients', you need something short, understandable, and recognized. Laying out all the procedural details (like air-gapped workstations) isn't useful to anyone.

Select an assurance standard and perform 3rd party audits, and make the results available.